# How to Use JS to sort LI by today's date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date

So:

I have a pricing table on a Bootstrap template, wherein there are 7 columns, one for each day of the week (it will be used to display events at a club). Fairly standard. It looks like this:

```
 <ul class="calen_table">
    <li class="calen_block">
        <h3>Sunday</h3>
        <div class="calen">
            <div class="calen_figure">
                <span class="calen_number">Style</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="stuff">
            <li>This!</li>
            <li>This!</li>
            <li>This!</li>
            <li>This!</li>
            <li>This!</li>
            <li>This!</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="calfooter">
            <a href="#" class="action_button">Promo</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="calen_block">
        <h3>Monday</h3>
        <div class="calen">
            <div class="calen_figure">
                <span class="calen_number">Style</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="stuff">
            <li>This!</li>
            <li>This!</li>
            <li>This!</li>
            <li>This!</li>
            <li>This!</li>
            <li>This!</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="calfooter">
            <a href="#" class="action_button">Promo</a>
        </div>
    </li>
and so on
```

What I would like to do is create a script so that the order of each of the columns is determined by the day of the week - so if a user goes to the site on a Sunday, the list goes Sunday, Monday, Tuesday...; wheres if a user goes to the site on a Wednesday, the list goes Wednesday, Thursday, Friday...

I always want to have all 7 showing, but would like the day of the week to set the order.

I know var day_of_week = date.getDay(); will get me the day of the week, and 0-6 are Sunday-Saturday respectively. I just can't work out how to apply that best to this case (if I should have 7 sets of 7, and have a trigger to show the correct set given the day; or if the

can actually be shuffled).

Any thoughts truly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm afraid that "any thoughts" questions are generally considered off-topic. Please make an effort and return with more specific questions.

Comment: You can take a look at [tinysort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/).

Comment: @isherwood - Apologies; I see know I should have gotten farther down the line before coming fort help.

Comment: @chenasraf - That looks like the perfect solution! Thank you most kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a approach like this :

```
var blocks = $('.calen_block');
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDay();
var temp = blocks.splice(0,day); //remove all the days before current day
temp = temp instanceof Array ? temp : [temp]; //splice doesn't return an array if you splice 1 element
blocks = blocks.concat(temp); // add the elements on after the current day
//empty the wrapper div and add them in the correct order
```

This approach goes from a html page where the days are added monday to sunday.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to use this in conjunction with "tinysort" linked above to accomplish my aim. I appreciate your input!